# LinkMasterFields property settings has produced this error "argument not optional" on rs.Seek

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

There are 2 tables: ToBeScheduled, and ScheduledItems.
One form: Form JobTkt

Goal: I am trying to update the just appended record with Form Controls using the DAO Method. If there is an easier method someone knows I am open to trying it.

I have written some code to try and update a record after it gets appended to table ToBeScheduled. I can get the append working fine, but when I try to update these few fields later I am having all kinds of issues. I am new to DAO method, so I am sure there is a mistake or two there. If this would be easier through SQL Update or something similar I would love to hear it, currently I am doing it this way because the Form JobTkt has multiple fields that need to be appended to table ToBeScheduled that are calculated right on the form. Taking them from the underlying table wouldn't help, as they don't exist yet and I am not aware of being able to reference form controls through SQL.

Anyway, here is my code:

```
'Declare Variables.
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim frm As Access.Form
    
    'Set Variable Values.
    Set frm = Forms![NICKELL JOBTKT 2B]
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("TO BE SCHEDULED", dbOpenDynaset, dbAppendOnly)

    rs.Edit
    
    rs.MoveFirst 'Load front end of the Recordset.
    rs.MoveLast 'Load back end of the Recordset.
    
    'Find the record that corresponds to the current open Job.
    rs.Seek ("JOB = " & Me.JobNumber)
    
    'Add missing fields to the Recordset.
    rs!FOOTAGE = frm("Order QTY")
    rs!RIP_QTY = frm("RIP_FTG")
    rs!["FTG/MLDR"] = frm("MLDR FTG")
    rs!P = frm("P")
    rs!SCRAP = frm("SCRAP%")
    rs!["FT/FCTR"] = frm("BD FTG FACTOR")
    
    'If species is MDF insert NMC for FTGE. If Lumber insert BDFT for FTGE.
    If frm("SPECIES") = "MDF" Then
        rs!FTGE = "NMC"
    Else
        rs!FTGE = frm("Field139")
        End If
        
    'Update and Close the Recordset to save changes.
    rs.Update
    rs.Close

    set rs = Nothing 'Clear Recordset
    set db = Nothing 'Clear Database

    MsgBox "Item successfully moved into the To Be Scheduled Table."
```

Don't feel afraid to ask me questions if things need clarifying!

Comment: Rather than using `Seek` (or even `FindFirst`), try opening a Recordset with just the record required in (`"SELECT * FROM [TO BE SCHEDULED] WHERE Job=" & Me.JobNumber`). Also, note that spaces in table/field names is not recommended.

Comment: I tested `OpenRecordset` with my own table and the options you used.  Afterward, `rs.Edit` triggered error 3021, "No current record." That is because [dbAppendOnly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordsetoptionenum-enumeration-dao) resulted in an empty recordset.  I can't figure out why you're not receiving the same error.

Comment: `rs.Edit` edits a single record. It needs to go **after** moving to the record you want to edit. -- Don't use `dbAppendOnly` if you want to edit existing records.

Comment: The question title seems unrelated to the content of the question. (?)

Comment: @HansUp Sorry, the error is during rs.Seek. About your second comment, I have done this method in 3 other places and not gotten that error, but I could see it causing the one I have. If I open the recordset append only, I can't very well update it now can I? I am going to try changing dpAppendOnly. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Applecore that seems like exactly what I'm trying to do here, albeit in a roundabout way. I hope that's a sign of my ignorance and not coding prowess lol. About your last point, unfortunately I have inherited this database and the decisions were not mine. It is a bit of a cluster, this is the 3rd version of the database. It is linked back to all of the tables in the second, and that one has dozens of linked tables back to the first. So there are a couple handfuls of tables I can't even access with design view to change any properties for. Working with this trainwreck has surely opened my eyes

Answer (score 1):

I think [Applecore's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73477752/linkmasterfields-property-settings-has-produced-this-error-argument-not-optiona#comment129757850_73477752) should be less trouble: instead of opening a recordset based on the full table and then navigating to the row you want to edit, base the recordset on a query which targets only that row.

Here is a brief outline using a parameter query.

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim frm As Access.Form
Dim strSelect As String

strSelect = "SELECT * FROM [TO BE SCHEDULED] WHERE JOB = [which_number];"
Set frm = Forms![NICKELL JOBTKT 2B]
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, strSelect)
qdf!which_number = Me.JobNumber ' supply the parameter value
Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset()

Debug.Print rs.BOF, rs.EOF, rs.RecordCount

If Not rs.EOF Then
    rs.Edit
    rs!FOOTAGE = frm("Order QTY")
    rs!RIP_QTY = frm("RIP_FTG")
    ' and so forth for the remaining field replacements
    rs.Update
End If
```

Notes:

1. `CreateQueryDef` with `vbNullString` (empty string) as its *Name* makes it a temporary query; it's discarded when the procedure ends.
2. `qdf!which_number` means the same as `qdf.Parameters("which_number")`; use the one which makes more sense to you.
3. I included the `Debug.Print` line just to demonstrate whether or not the recordset is empty.  View its output in the Immediate window; <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> will take you there.